# Which of the following is homomorphism from $Z_{8} \to Z_{12} ?$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Which of the following is homomorphism from $Z_{8} \to Z_{12} ?$

$1). f(5) = 7$

$2). f(3)=8$

$3). f(2)=3$

$4)$ None of these.

Since, in homorphism, order of image always divides order of pre image, so if order of image doesn't divide order of preimage, then the function cannot be homomorphic.

So, 1st and 2nd option are incorrect. Now in 3rd option, order of image in $Z_{12}$, which is $4$, divides order of image which is also $4$. But this condition doesn't imply homomorphism. 
So, how can I check if 3rd option is correct or not?

Comment: What would f(1) be in case 3?  Wouldn't 2 times f(1) be an even?

Comment: $f(1)=1$ and $f(1^{2}) = (f(1))^{2} = 1^{2} = 2$ which is not $3$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Mathsaddict You haven't said whether this is about groups or about rings. Is this about groups or about rings?

Comment: @Arthur, about groups.

Answer (score 1):

According to me the answer is d.

We know that if $f\colon G\to H$ is a group homomorphism, so $G/\ker f\cong Im f$.

But in the first case $Im f=\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ that isn't isomorphic to any subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$

In the second case $\ker f=0$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ hasn't subgroup whose order is 8

In the third case we have $\mathbb{Z}_{8}/\ker f\cong\mathbb{Z}_{4}$, so we need $\ker f\cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. The only subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ is $\langle 4\rangle$, but $f(4)=2f(2)=6\ne 0$, so $f$ is not an homomorphism.